# How to set alignment to the left when using htf.tableheader?

Tags: html, oracle, plsql

I have been using htf (hypertext function) to create table. Without setting anything my table header has been aligning to center. How should i set it to align to the left? However, my table data has been aligning to the left.

```
v_html := htf.tableopen('border = 1','left',null ,null,'cellpadding = 10') || chr(10);
v_html := v_html || htf.tableheader('Line');
v_html := v_html || htf.tableheader('Quantity');
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowopen;
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(i.line);
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(htf.escape_sc(i.quantity));
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowclose;
v_html := v_html || htf.tableclose;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can adjust it with **Style** tag in your HTML like this:

```
<HTML>
  <style>
  td, th {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 15px;
  }
  </style>
    <BODY>
        <!-- YOUR TABlE HERE ALONG WITH OTHER TAGS -->
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

With htf function:

```
 V_HTML := V_HTML || HTF.STYLE('td, th { text-align: left; padding-left: 5px; }');
```

Comment: I just got the answer, all you need is just add a left. v_html := v_html || htf.tableheader( 'Line','left'); and it works.

Comment: @Jane yes it works, but if you have a lot of table headers(like the picture) this one saves some time